# D3 V4 getting data from brush selection

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to get all the nodes within a d3 brush selection window. How do I approach this? I have tried using `d3.event.selection` but it doesn't seem to work.

```
var brush = d3.brush()
     .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
     .on("start", brushstart)
     .on("brush", brushing)
     .on("end", brushend);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr('class', 'brush')
      .call(brush);

      // colors selected nodes in red
      function color_node(node) {
          // return "red";
          if (node.selected) { return "red"; }
          else { return "orange";}
      }

      function brushstart() {
          // do whatever you want on brush start
      }

      function brushing() {
        console.log("In brushing");
        var e = brush.extent().call();

        svg.selectAll("circle").style("fill", function(d) {
           truth = e[0][0] <= brushX.invert(d.x) && brushX.invert(d.x) <= e[1][0]
                && e[0][1] <= brushY.invert(d.y) && brushY.invert(d.y) <= e[1][1];
           value = truth ? "black" : color_node(d);
           return value;
        })
        ;

      }

      function brushend() {
        console.log("in brush end");
        // console.log(d3.brushSelection());
        var e = brush.extent().call();
        // console.log(d3.event.selection)
        if (d3.event.selection === null) svg.selectAll("circle").attr("class", function(d) {
            d.selected=false;
        });

        svg.selectAll("circle").attr("fill", function(d) {
           truth = e[0][0] <= brushX.invert(d.x) && brushX.invert(d.x) <= e[1][0]
                && e[0][1] <= brushY.invert(d.y) && brushY.invert(d.y) <= e[1][1];
           if (truth) { d.selected = true; }
           value = truth ? "red" : color_node(d);
           return value;
        });

      }
```

The `svg` within `brushing` & `brushend` functions fills the nodes in my graph with black color. What I want is that to replace `svg` with the selection of my brush so I can process only selected nodes.

`d3.event.selection` seems to be a solutions. But It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Please share the entire working code snippet.

Comment: @WiniSan  It's a bit more lengthy, Can you please share in what part you actually are interested in?